# InnerHTML directive ignoring html tags in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, innerhtml, angular-directive

I would like make a part of my text bold .

I get a text from a specific file.

`"INFORMATION": "<b>Here's an </b> example of text"`

I would make `Here an` bold.

In my component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.definition = INFORMATION
}
```

In my html template

```
<span [innerHTML]="definition | translate"></span>
```

What I get is:

Here's an example of text

What I expect

**Here's an** example of text

It's like Angular is ignoring html tags

Comment: What happens if you remove the translate pipe (and just use `[innerHTML]="definition"` where definition is the HTML)?

Comment: I get  the word `INFORMATION` printed

Comment: Try to change the `definition` variable and assign the value `<b>Here's an </b> example of text` to it directly and then `[innerHTML]="definition"` in the template

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz for this? I have checked it just and it displaying me exactly as your expected output.

Comment: Shouldnt that be `this.definition = 'INFORMATION'`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not Angular who is faulty here - but the translate pipe.

Binding the HTML to `[innerHTML]` (or `[outerHTML]`) is the correct way to render html from a variable, so the issue must be the translation pipe that performs some logic to filter away the HTML tags.

In case you're using ngx-translate:

The binding will happen correctly the first time the pipe resolves and you will get your HTML in your innerHTML.

But the next time the pipe resolves it will only take the content of the element.

Comment: I use ngx-translate, I get a strange behavoir, sometimes when I reload the page the bold tag is applied then it disapear .

Comment: That explains a lot. Likely what's happening is that the first time the pipe resolves it properly applies the HTML, but the next time it only applies it on the actual content of the element

Comment: Any idea to make ngx-translate working with html tag, I'm doing like here https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/145 but it does not working